# Add single cells to a table

Tags: tables

It is probably one of the easier questions, but I couldn't find a solution yet or think of a good search term for it. I basically want to replicate the last row of this table:

[image]

I thought of using multicolumn somehow, but I can't make the columns 1,4 and 5 disappear that way. Maybe multicolumn is also not the way to go and I can just attach two separate cells without a separator to make it look like in the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend vertical lines in tables, but here is a solution to this problem...

Single cells or a cluster of single cells can be obtained with `\multicolumn` and `\cline` in the right manner, of course.

*Vanished* cells are `\multicolumn{number of cells}{l}{}`, omitting the `|` here.

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{l|}}
\hline
This & is & a & bad & example & of & a & table \tabularnewline
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Proved!} & \multicolumn{5}{l}{} \tabularnewline
\cline{3-3} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, somehow I didn't think of leaving multicolumn empty. Why don't you recommend vertical lines, btw?

Comment: @LatexGuest Just read the documentation to `booktabs` which will most probably be everything Herr Hupfer would answer to your question. Worth a read, btw. Great package.

Answer (score 1):

I was much too slow but just in order to show `siunitx`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE,group-separator=.,group-four-digits}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format=2.0]|S[table-format=5.2]|S[table-format=6.2]|S[table-format=5.2]|S[table-format=5.2]|}
    % put the € symbol in your header row as it is redundant.
    \hline
    7 & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\\hline
    8 & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\\hline
    9 & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\\hline
    10 & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Summe Zinsen:} & \multicolumn{1}{S[table-format=6.2]|}{115569.00} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{} \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

With `booktabs`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE,group-separator=.,group-four-digits}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.0]S[table-format=5.2]S[table-format=6.2]S[table-format=5.2]S[table-format=5.2]}
    % put the € symbol in your header row as it is redundant.
    \toprule
        {Number} & {value in €}  & {value in €} & {value in €} & {value in €}\\
    \midrule
    7  & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\
    8  & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\
    9  & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\
    10 & 28362.47 & 2694.43 & 28362.47 & 0.00 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Summe Zinsen:} & 115569.00 & & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'll remember that, thanks. I actually generate tables with a little script so far so I don't have to input the numbers or format them with the thousands separators by hand. Very cool solution!

Comment: @LatexGuest You can even input a mixture of decimal-dot and decimal-comma numbers and it will handle everything right. Great package for sure.